415 Unsupported Media Type when trying to get access token for Hubspot OAuth
I am trying to get an access token for an OAuth with Hubspot via a node.js backend application. I am following the following description:https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/oauth-quickstart-guide
To get the access token I have written the following method:
function getAccessToken(code){
    const formData = {
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,   
        client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
        redirect_uri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
        code: code
    };
    axios.post('https://api.hubapi.com/oauth/v1/token', 
        { 
            form: formData 
        },
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }
        
    )
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
}

When the call is executed I am always getting a 415 Unsupported Media Type error.

I have also tried if with CURL, and there it works fine. My CURL command is:
  curl -X POST https://api.hubapi.com/oauth/v1/token -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=authorization_code" -d "client_id=yyyy" -d "client_secret=xxx" -d "redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/api/hubspot/callback&scope=crm.schemas.deals.read%20oauth%20crm.objects.leads.read%20crm.objects.users.read%20crm.objects.contacts.write%20crm.objects.appointments.read%20crm.objects.companies.read%20crm.lists.read%20crm.objects.deals.read%20crm.schemas.contacts.read%20crm.objects.contacts.read%20crm.schemas.companies.read" -d "code=zzzz"

Can you help me what I am missing in my node.js code?

I solved it by changing the header to:
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        charset: 'utf8',
        accept: '*/*'
    }

